# How can I sync Passwords and keys data between two Ubuntu PCs?

Tags: password, sync

I have an office and a personal PC, and I want to sync my "passwords and key" data between these two PCs.

Right now, I am using MEGAsync to sync `~/.gnupg` & `~/.local/share/keyrings` but it's not syncing data (I am not getting passwords stored via `secret-tool` in one PC to another).

Is there a better way?

Thanks.